# A question about limits

Tags: limits

Using the line $y=x$ and the parabola $y=x^{2}$ in the calculation of  $\lim_{\left ( x,y \right )\rightarrow \left ( 0,0 \right )}\displaystyle\frac{x^4 \sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^4 + y^2}$ it turns out that this limit is $0$. But to affirm that $\lim_{\left ( x,y \right )\rightarrow \left ( 0,0 \right )}\displaystyle\frac{x^4 \sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^4 + y^2}=0$, it is necessary to use the definition of limit, this is $\left | \displaystyle\frac{x^4 \sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^4 + y^2} \right |< \varepsilon $, whenever $0< \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}< \delta $.

How to find the $\varepsilon =\varepsilon \left ( \delta  \right )$ relationship?

Comment: there are other distance metrics that you can use.....$d((0,0),(x,y)) = x^2 + y^2$ is almost always easier that adding in the square root.  Or the "taxi cab metric" $d((0,0),(x,y)) = |x| + |y|$ will often work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We see that
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{x^{4}}{x^{4}+y^{2}}\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})\right|&\leq\dfrac{x^{4}(x^{2}+y^{2})}{x^{4}+y^{2}}\\
&\leq x^{2}+y^{2}\\
&<\delta^{2}\\
&<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
by choosing $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$.